# I am performing ngclick show hide but can't get any output

Tags: angularjs

i am using angular 1.6 and trying to perform ng-click hide show of profile data but anyhow i dont know where i am going wrong.
here the code

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-10" ng-controller="profile">
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <a ng-click="edit-form = ! edit-form"> <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x" style="cursor:pointer;color:#f7972f;"> </i> </a>
    </div>
        <div class="image-upload edit-picture">
            <label for="file-input">
                <i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x" style="cursor:pointer;color:#f7972f;"> </i>
            </label>
            <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
        </div>
        <img src="amit.jpg" class="img img-circle edit-image" style="width:150px;">
        <h3> Amit Singh Chauhan </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" ng-show="edit-form"> 
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10" >
        <form action="" novalidate="novalidate">
            <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap first-name"><input type="text" name="first-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="First Name"></span></p>
            <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap last-name"><input type="text" name="last-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Last Name"></span></p>
            <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email-address"><input type="email" name="email-address" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="E-mail Address"></span></p>
            <div><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Comment"></textarea></span></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Save Profile" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit mkd-contact3"><span class="ajax-loader"></span></div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 <script>
     var app = angular.module("myApp", []).controller ("profile",  function         ($scope){
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Try giving a name to the form as <form name="EditForm">

Comment: but why form name should be like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `edit-form` to `editForm`.

Comment: still nothing happen

Comment: @amitchauhan works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/kxPG3sSGcep9JqlHZgOt?p=preview, so there's still something wrong in your code. Create a plnkr reproducing the issue. And simplify your code to only show the relevant parts, but to show them **all**.

Comment: actually its whole theme so cant upload the whole damn project

Comment: @amitchauhan hence *simplify your code to only show the relevant parts, but to show them all.* All you need is an index.html with an ng-app, a link with ng-click, and an element with ng-show. The rest is irrelevant

Comment: in my header.php file in html tag i define ng-app="myApp" then using routing method . then i put the profile.html whole page data above